# Issue transfering value using notifications | Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller that contains a button that, when pressed, presents a camera view controller that allows the user to scan a barcode and  return to the first view controller that launched it with the value of the barcode.

**Camera View Controller is presented:**

```
let ScannerView = scanBarcode()
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ScannerView)
        navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
        self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Function executed when barcode scanned:**

```
 func processScan() {
  print("Process Scanned")
  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("scannedInfo"), object: nil,
  userInfo:["barcodeValue": "123","value2": "Yes"])

  dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
  viewController1().observeScanned()
 }
```

**Function called on dismiss from ViewController1**

```
func observeScanned() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(
                                            self.ScanInfo(notification:)),
                                           name: Notification.Name("ScanInfo"),
                                           object: nil)
} 


@objc func ScanInfo(notification: Notification) {
    print("ScanInfo")
    barcode = notification.userInfo?["barcodeValue"] as? String
    value2 = notification.userInfo?["value2"] as? String
    print(barcode)
    print(value2)
}
```

The issue is the function the notification observer does not seem to be triggered and the values for barcodeValue and value2 are not transfer to ViewController1. `print(barcode)` and `print(value2)` are never printed. While I understand I can easily rely on ViewDidAppear if I presented the modal as `.fullscreen` I much rather presenting as a formsheet or equivalent, where the screen is not full used.

Comment: You're observing a notification named `ScanInfo` but you didn't show any code where you're posting this notification. Does that happen? When?

Comment: @TomHarrington it is under the function processScan() please see the second snippet of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems here.

First, this code:

```
viewController1().observeScanned()
```

Creates a new instance of `viewController1` and calls its `observeScanned` function - This view controller instance isn't on screen and will be thrown away as soon as this line executes.

Even if you were invoking the `observedScanned()` function on the correct instance, it is too late.

This is your second problem.  You posted the notification two lines earlier.  When a notification is posted it is delivered to observers that have registered for that notification. An observer after the notification has been posted won't get that notification, it will only get subsequent notifications.

It looks like you are mixing a delegation pattern and notifications. You only need one.

If you just want to use notifications then you can call `observeScanned` from `viewDidLoad` in `viewController1` and then just post the notification in your `scanBarcode` view controller. There is no need for `scanBarcode` to explicitly invoke any method on `viewController1` - The point of `Notification`s is to provide decoupling of senders and observers.

If you just want to use delegation then you can declare a protocol

```
protocol ScannerDelegate {
    func didScan(barcodeValue: String, value2: String) -> Void
}
```

Then `ViewController1` can conform to this protocol and set itself as the delegate on the `ScanBarcode` instance:

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController, ScannerDelegate {

    // ...
        let scannerView = scanBarcode()
        scannerView.delegate = self 
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ScannerView)
        navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
        self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)

   //...

    func didScan(barcodeValue: String, value2: String) -> Void {
        print("ScanInfo")
        print(barcodeValue)
        print(value2)
    }
}
```

Finally, your `ScanBarcode` needs to provide a `delegate` property and invoke the delegate method

```
class ScanBarcode: UIViewController {

    var delegate: ScannerDelegate?

    func processScan() {
        print("Process Scanned")
        self.delegate?.didScan(barcodeValue:"123", value2:"456")
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
    }
}
```

One last thing.  You should get into the habit of following Swift naming conventions.  It doesn't affect the way your code works but it makes your code more readable to others.

- Types (classes, structs, protocols, enums) use UpperCamelCase so `ViewController1` not `viewController1`
- Variables & constants use lowerCamelCase so `scannerView` not `ScannerView`

I have made these changes in my version of your code in this answer so you can see what I am referring to.

Comment: Thank you very much, I now understand how to properly use delegates for transferring information - not sure who downvoted.

Comment: If I may ask, can you take a look at my other post, I appreciate your help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69248393/issue-initiating-view-controllers-based-on-array-swift-5